# Maintain a wallet on 2 devices

Tags: wallet

Is it possible 2 maintain a single HD wallet on two devices? Assume a laptop and phone. My first thought is to install a HD wallet on the second device and create a new wallet using the original wallet words.

Answer (score 1):

Yes with an HD wallet you can use as many devices as you like.

However you may want to ask yourself why you are doing this. More devices = more possible attack surfaces.

Using different HD wallets has the benefit of the losing one (to a keylogger, etc) not causing loss to your Bitcoin in the others.

Why not keep a small amount of BTC in your mobile HD wallet for everyday use and have a little more in a seperate laptop HD wallet and the majority in a seperate cold storage HD wallet?

Comment: Yes, I have considered and understand your concerns. The wallet(s) would only hold a small amount. I am looking into other storage methods, such as paper wallets, but am concerned about the seemingly difficulties of importing them into software wallets.